# Mongodb merge structure

Tags: json, mongodb, upsert

I have the following structure

```
{
id: id
a: a,
b: b,
c: [{ d: d }, {e: e}]
}
```

what command do I use to update b and d keeping the structure of the other fields. And if the record does not exist, create a new one. I was using the command below, but it doesn't maintain the structure.

```
"multi": true, 
"upsert": true, 
"ordered": false, 
"updates":[
{"q": {"id": id}, 
"u": {"$set": {"id": id, "b": 0, "c": [{"d": 0}]}}}
```

i am using "version" : "3.4.24"

Comment: is `{ d: d }` always at index 0?

Comment: Can you add expected result in the question?

Comment: {
id: id,
a: a,
b: 0,
c: [{ d: 0 }, {e: e}]
}

Comment: Have you tried using array filters?

Comment: I use the id to fetch the record

Comment: I got it       "u": {"$set": {"id": id, "b": 0, "c.0.d" = 0 }}  this way it keeps the other fields